# Input inserts U+200C character automatically on : (colon) key

Tags: gnome, keyboard

I've had Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 xenial for a while and I've had recently upgraded using `-d` to Bionic. I'm currently using my old GNOME‌ environment still.

The problem is that whenever I hit the <kbd>:</kbd> key, a hidden `U+200C` unicode character is inserted. This happens in different IDEs and editors including PyCharm and VisualStudio Code. This is very annoying...

What can I do about it?

Comment: Do you have a `~/.inputrc` file? what is the output of `bind -p | grep -E $'"\x3a"'` in a terminal?

Comment: Hiiiiiiii :D No I don't have a `~/.inputrc` file and the output of the command you said is `":": self-insert`

My problem still persists though :(